Tailwind class are not working in my storybook part in nuxt3
I have just launched a nuxt 3.11 project to which I added tailwindcss and when I launch my application my classes load without any problem.
However, after installing storybook (and some problems due to changes in version 8(thanks to this issue: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/26306)) I notice that my tailwind classes do not load.
Here my fresh project : https://github.com/FlorientPlouvin/nuxt-starter
I tried to install tailwind via its nuxt plugin but nothing changed.
Here are my preview.js and main.js files
preview.js
/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3').Preview } */
import "../assets/css/main.css";

const preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

main.js
/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3-vite').StorybookConfig } */
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
const config = {
  stories: ["../stories/**/*.mdx", "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|mjs|ts|vue)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@chromatic-com/storybook",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  async viteFinal(config) {
    // Merge custom configuration into the default config
    const { mergeConfig } = await import("vite");

    return mergeConfig(config, {
      plugins: [vue()],
    });
  },
};
export default config;

nuxt.config.ts
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ["~/assets/css/main.css"],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/storybook"],
  storybook: {
    url: "http://localhost:6006",
    storybookRoute: "/__storybook__",
    port: 6006,
  },
});

tailwindcss :
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./stories/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
    "./layouts/**/*.vue",
    "./pages/**/*.vue",
    "./plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "./app.vue",
    "./error.vue",
  ],
};

